# Branch IO deep link Custom Alias is not Working. Same link is not sharing in two different Apps?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, branch.io

I am creating a social media type application in which I created a sharing profile through Deep link of Branch IO.

Issue : I create a unique username of each user and that is use as sharing link.
Example : username : sumit1698
sharing link : https://l.hire.in/sumit1698

But When I share this to profile first time after creating it works but when I share the same profile to another app. It shows error

> {"error":{"code":409,"message":"Link alias conflict: l.hire.in/sumit1698"}}

I am using Custom Alias In Branch IO.

```
Future<void> buildBranchIOLink(ArtistModel artistModel) async {

BranchUniversalObject buo = BranchUniversalObject(
    canonicalIdentifier: '${artistModel.uid}',
    //canonicalUrl: '',
    title: 'View my profile @${artistModel.name}',
    // imageUrl: '${artistModel.profile}',
    imageUrl: '',
    contentDescription: 'Visit A4H app for booking',
    keywords: ['Plugin', 'Branch', 'Flutter'],
    // publiclyIndex: true,
    locallyIndex: true,
    contentMetadata: BranchContentMetaData()
      ..addCustomMetadata('artist_uid', '${artistModel.uid}')
    // ..addCustomMetadata('artist_id', artistModel.id),
    );

String username = artistModel.systemName != null
    ? artistModel.systemName
    : artistModel.name;


BranchLinkProperties lp = BranchLinkProperties(
    alias: '${username.replaceAll(" ", ".")}', //define link url,
    channel: 'message',
    feature: 'sharing',
    stage: 'new share',
    tags: ['one', 'two', 'three']);
lp.addControlParam('url', 'http://www.google.com');
lp.addControlParam('url2', 'http://flutter.dev');

BranchResponse response = await FlutterBranchSdk.showShareSheet(
    buo: buo,
    linkProperties: lp,
    messageText: 'Hire ${artistModel.name} with A4H',
    androidMessageTitle: '${artistModel.name}',
    androidSharingTitle: '${artistModel.name}');

if (response.success) {
  print('showShareSheet Success');
} else {
  print('Error : ${response.errorCode} - ${response.errorMessage}');
}

bool success = await FlutterBranchSdk.listOnSearch(buo: buo);
print(success);
```

}